# asp.net dynamic variable in hyperlink

Tags: html

I'm having a little trouble using an asp.net:hyperlink control.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="someId" runat="server" NavigateUrl="pages/somepage.aspx?language=<%=CurrentLanguageNo%>"></asp:HyperLink>
```

the resulting url is like this

```
http://localhost/web/standard/pages/somepage.aspx?language=<%=CurrentLanguageNo%>
```

but obviously I don't want it to literally be <%=CurrentLanguageNo%> but rather the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to specify the entire NavigateUrl within the <%=%>

so you have 2 choices (actually there are plenty more but let's not waste time):

```
NavigateUrl='<%= "pages/somepage.aspx?language=" + CurrentLanguageNo%>'
```

Or you put directly the entire string in the variable CurrentLanguageNo

Other possibility is to keep your NavigateUrl="pages/somepage.aspx?language=" and then on the code behind add CurrentLanguageNo

```
objLink.NavigateUrl += CurrentLanguageNo;
```

If you use VB.NET remember to replace + with &

Comment: That's great thank you SeraphnimFoA, I used the code behind method you suggested

Comment: If you do that make sure that you don't append the Language to the Link more than once.